# UserPaymentInformation matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement UserPaymentInformation update in django rest framework

But for request http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments/update/  (PUT)

I have an error

> DoesNotExist at /api/payments/update/
> UserPaymentInformation matching query does not exist.

Full stacktrace https://pastebin.com/WVjQ5aYN

**models.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformation(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    bik = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name="payment_information",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-pk",)
        verbose_name = "user payment information"
        verbose_name_plural = "user payment informations"
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPaymentInformation
        fields = ("id", "full_name", "card_number", "account_number", "bik")
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformationUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedDriver,)
    serializer_class = UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer
    queryset = serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.version == "1.0":
            return UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer
        # return UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer2

    def mark_user_as_new(self):
        user = self.request.user
        user.is_new_user = True
        user.save()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop("partial", False)
        instance = self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.get(
            user=self.request.user
        )

        self.mark_user_as_new()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instance, data=request.data, partial=partial
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response({"result": serializer.data})
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: instance = self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.get(
            user=self.request.user
        )
Do you have a UserPaymentInformation object for that user in that model? If you don't then it will throw that error.